# How to change the text of place holder in WordPress SW Max Shop theme?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the place holder text with something more text. How can it be changed?

[image]

Comment: Please include the image directly, do not just post a link to an image and provide more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post to fit within those guidelines. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

Got to `searchform.php`

```
<form method="get" class="searchform themeform" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
          <div>
             <input type="text" class="search" name="s" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','hueman'); ?>';" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','hueman'); ?>')this.value='';" value="<?php _e('To search type and hit enter','hueman'); ?>" />
          </div>
</form>
```

Change placeholder text according to your requirement. :)

Comment: Brother with this action nothing happening. The result is same as previous.        the code i found their before that is as below:   <form role="search" method="get" class="form-search searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <label class="hide"><?php _e('Search for:', 'maxshop'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if (is_search()) { echo get_search_query(); } ?>" name="s" class="search-query" placeholder=" SAP ">
  <button type="submit" class="fa fa-search button-search-pro form-button"></button>
</form>